Ubuntu :: Dummy Output
I am running Ubuntu 24.04 and have a Dell XPS laptop.  My speakers only show Dummy Output, and there is no sound.  How do I fix this?

This question is similar to: Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Which Dell XPS Model?
